# Proof of $(A \times B) \cup (B \times A) \subset (A \cup B) \times (A \cup B)$.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

I have to proof that $(A \times B) \cup (B \times A) \subset (A \cup B) \times (A \cup B)$.

I wrote a proof and I wondered if it's right and if I can do something to make it better.

Take an arbitrary $(e_1,e_2) \in (A \times B) \cup (B \times A)$. We will prove that $(e_1,e_2) \in (A \cup B) \times (A \cup B)$.

$(e_1,e_2) \in (A \times B)\cup(B \times A)\iff (e_1,e_2) \in \{(a,b) \mid a \in A \wedge b \in B \}$ or $(e_1,e_2) \in \{(b,a)\mid b\in B \wedge a \in A \} \iff (e_1,e_2) \in \{(x,y)\mid x \in A\cup B \wedge y \in A \cup B\} \implies (e_1,e_2) \in (A \cup B) \times (A \cup B). \square$

Comment: The second implication only goes one way, from left to right, hence should be a $\implies$. That's enough to conclude the proof, we don't need the other direction. The rest looks fine to me. (As an alternative proof, I'd have exploited the law $X \cup Y \subseteq Z$ if and only if $X \subseteq Z \land Y \subseteq Z$.) Also, I assumed your $\subset$ to mean $\subseteq$, otherwise the statement is false in general.

Comment: I believe that you should use $\leftrightarrow$ instead of $\Leftrightarrow$. Also, I can see that the second $\Leftrightarrow$ is not true, it should be $\rightarrow$.

Comment: @TranKhanh Why should I use ↔?

Comment: @user34, my bad, actually I mean **iff** (if and only if) not $\leftrightarrow$ (for convention only if your proof follows the **iff** strategy), $\Leftrightarrow$ is perfectly fine. Also the second is $\Rightarrow$.

Comment: I corrected my proof.